# AVAudioEngine synchronization for MIDI playback and recording

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

**Question 1**
My first question concerns playback synchronization when using an `AVAudioPlayerNode` and an `AVAudioSequencer` for MIDI. Basically I'm trying to play something over MIDI, but they need to be perfectly synchronized.

I'm aware there are sync methods for `AVAudioPlayerNode`s, but the sequencer does not seem to have something like that.

Currently I've tried using `CAMediaTime() + delay` and `usleep` on separate threads, but they don't seem to work very well.

**Question 2** I'm using the tap on the `engine.inputNode` to get the recording, separate from the music playback. However, it seems like the recording starts earlier. When I compare the recorded data with the original playback, the difference is around 300 ms. I could start recording 300 ms later, but even then, that does not guarantee precise sync and is likely to be machine dependent.

So my question is, what would be a good way to ensure that the recording starts precisely at the moment the playback starts?

Answer (score 7):

For synchronizing audio io, it is often best to create a reference time, then use this time for all timing related calculations.

[AVAudioPlayerNode.play(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayernode/1389304-playz) is what you need for the player. For the tap you need to filter out (partial) buffers manually using the time provided in the closure. AVAudioSequencer unfortunately does not have a facility for starting at a specific time, but you can get a reference time correlated to a beat with an already playing sequencer using [hostTime(forBeats)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosequencer/1386184-hosttime). If I remember correctly, you cannot set the sequencer to a negative position, so this is not ideal.

Here's a hacky workaround that should yield very accurate results:

AVAudioSequencer has to be started before getting a reference time, offset all of your midi data by 1, start the sequencer, then immediately get the reference time correlated to beat 1, then synchronize the start of the player to this time, and also use it to filter out unwanted audio captured by the tap.

```
func syncStart() throws {
    //setup
    sequencer.currentPositionInBeats = 0
    player.scheduleFile(myFile, at: nil)
    player.prepare(withFrameCount: 4096)

    // Start and get reference time of beat 1
    try sequencer.start()
    // Wait until first render cycle completes or hostTime(forBeats) will err - AVAudioSequencer is fragile :/
    while (self.sequencer.currentPositionInBeats <= 0) { usleep(UInt32(0.001 * 1000000.0)) }
    var nsError: NSError?
    let hostTime = sequencer.hostTime(forBeats: 1, error: &nsError)
    let referenceTime = AVAudioTime(hostTime: hostTime)

    // AVAudioPlayer is great for this.
    player.play(at: referenceTime)

    // This just rejects buffers that come too soon. To do this right you need to record partial buffers.
    engine.inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: nil) { (buffer, audioTime) in
        guard audioTime.hostTime >= referenceTime.hostTime else { return }
        self.recordBuffer(buffer: buffer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This unfortunately didn't work for me because `hostTime(forBeats:error:)` kept causing a crash, but it definitely set me on the correct path. I'll reference the answer in my own answer, and post what I did.

Comment: There, I fixed it by waiting for the first render cycle to complete before calling `hostTime(forBeats:)`

Answer (score 0):

[dave234's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52960011/2828100) unfortunately didn't work for me because `hostTime(forBeats:error:)` kept crashing even after starting the sequencer first. (It did work when I dispatched asynchronously after some delay, but that would cause further complication). However, it provided valuable insight into synchronization methods, and here's what I did:

```
var refTime: AVAudioTime

if isMIDIPlayer {
    sequencer!.tracks.forEach { $0.offsetTime = 1 }
    sequencer!.currentPositionInBeats = 0

    let sec = sequencer!.seconds(forBeats: 1)
    let delta = AVAudioTime.hostTime(forSeconds: sec) + mach_absolute_time()
    refTime = AVAudioTime(hostTime: delta)

    try sequencer!.start()
} else {
    player!.prepare(withFrameCount: 4096)

    let delta = AVAudioTime.hostTime(forSeconds: 0.5) + mach_absolute_time()
    refTime = AVAudioTime(hostTime: delta)

    player!.play(at: refTime)
}

mixer.installTap(
    onBus: 0,
    bufferSize: 8,
    format: mixer.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
) { [weak self] (buffer, time) in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    guard time.hostTime >= refTime.hostTime else { print("NOPE"); return }

    do {
        try strongSelf.recordFile!.write(from: buffer)
    } catch {
        // TODO: Handle error
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Some explanation about the code snippet:

- I have made a generic `AudioPlayer` that can play both MIDI and other song files, and the code is from a method inside `AudioPlayer`.
- `sequencer` is used for MIDI playback.
- `player` is used for other song files.

MIDI playback synchronization uses a similar method like so:

```
midi!.sequencer!.tracks.forEach { $0.offsetTime = 1 }

let sec = midi!.sequencer!.seconds(forBeats: 1)
let delta = AVAudioTime.hostTime(forSeconds: sec) + mach_absolute_time()
let refTime = AVAudioTime(hostTime: delta)

do {
    try midi!.play()
} catch {
    // TODO: Add error handler
    print(error)
}

song2.playAtTime(refTime)
```

Here, `midi` is the `AVAudioSequencer` object, and `song2` is the `AVAudioPlayerNode` that plays a regular song.

Works like a charm!

Comment: This is a pretty inaccurate method here. If sample accuracy is not needed it may be fine, but the method I posted below should get you very accurate results.

Comment: @dave234 I wonder where you got the notion of inaccuracy. As far as I can tell, both the `AVAudioSequencer` and `AVAudioPlayerNode` is scheduled to play at a future point in time as counted by the `mach_absolute_time()`, a.k.a. host time. The only inaccuracy can stem from the write buffer being too large in size, which your code has also. I've personally tested my code. Have you tested yours?

Comment: You are making the assumption that the machine time when `start()` is called will correlate with the actual start time of the sequencer, but this isn't the case. The actual start time of the sequence after `start()` is called is undocumented, but empirically it is the start of the next audio render cycle - if you called `prepareToPlay()` prior. As far as testing goes, compare `delta` with `hostTime(forBeats: 0)` and you'll see the discrepancy using this method.

Comment: Yeah well as long as people hear notes played at the same time they'll be happy. They won't come to be saying one player is playing 10 CPU ticks fast, so I'm done here.

Comment: It’s more like 0.02 seconds, but if it sounds good, it sounds good :)